# Continue the script if there is no item on the page javascript

Tags: javascript, download, element, imacros, skip

I'm writing a script on imacros and javascript. The script clicks on the buttons on the page, after which the dialog box for selecting the file download (pdf) appears.

I check various numbers through the site and search for them a pdf file. In the process of the script, the situation may arise when the page does not have the desired item (the data has not yet been received and the button for downloading the file will not be active).

Who knows how to write a script that at that moment when the desired element on the page does not turn out to be a script that continued to work and took other values ​​to enter into the form to then download the file?

```
for (i=1;i<=3; i++) {
var macro; // Create a variable macro
macro = "CODE:"; // Enter the code for the macro
macro += "URL GOTO=http://www.dpd.ru/ols/order/order.do2"+"\n";// Go to the website
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:datePickup CONTENT=my date"+"\n";// Set the date
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:filter_show"+"\n";// Advanced Search
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:orderNum CONTENT=my number"+"\n"; //Set number of dispatch
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_refresh_btn"+"\n";// Show orders
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:order_list_form ATTR=NAME:orderId CONTENT=YES"+"\n"; // Select document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_dialog_btn"+"\n"; // Printing a document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_form_btn"+"\n";// Download window
macro += "TAB T=2"+"\n";// Opening the second tab
macro += "TAB T=1"+"\n";// Open the tab
macro += "TAG POS=12 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:close"+"\n"; // Close download menu
iimPlay(macro) // Run the variable
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ChD2.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your English (especially the 3rd paragraph), sorry. Could you add a comment in Russian?

Comment: Привет!
Пишу скрипт на imacros и javascript. Скрипт нажимает на кнопки на странице, после чего появляется диалоговое окно выбора загрузки файла (pdf).

Я проверяю различные номера через сайт и ищу для них файл pdf. В процессе работы скрипта может возникнуть ситуация когда на странице не будет нужного элемента (данные еще не были получены и  кнопка для скачивания файла будет не активна). 

Как нужно написать скрипт что бы в тот момент когда нужного элемента на странице не окажется скрипт продолжал работу и брал другие значения для ввода в форму что бы затем скачать файл?

Comment: So you want [if-else in imacros](https://www.google.com/search?q=imacros+if+else)? Which element may be not present (what line of macros)?

Comment: macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:order_list_form ATTR=NAME:orderId CONTENT=YES"+"\n"; // Select document

Comment: I can't find any free version of imacros that works in a browser. Sorry, I give up. I advise you to search for how to make `if-else` with imacros.

Comment: http://pastenow.ru/90b61e19c132c46a9e37dbe59ac5b2a1

Comment: Есть возможность пообщаться в skype? (vorontcov_ea)

Comment: In JavaScript (and other languages) it is called [scraping](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+scraping)

Answer (score 0):

im not very clear with your English. But based on what i understand, you want the script to continue to work, even if the element is not present right? If that's your need, you want to use the "`SET !ERRORIGNORE YES`" command at the start of your code.

Updated code:

```
for (i=1;i<=3; i++) {
var macro; // Create a variable macro
macro = "CODE:"; // Enter the code for the macro
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; //Set script to ignore error and continue work 
macro += "URL GOTO=http://www.dpd.ru/ols/order/order.do2"+"\n";// Go to the website
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:datePickup CONTENT=my date"+"\n";// Set the date
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:filter_show"+"\n";// Advanced Search
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:orderNum CONTENT=my number"+"\n"; //Set number of dispatch
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_refresh_btn"+"\n";// Show orders
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:order_list_form ATTR=NAME:orderId CONTENT=YES"+"\n"; // Select document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_dialog_btn"+"\n"; // Printing a document
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:order_delivery_proof_print_form_btn"+"\n";// Download window
macro += "TAB T=2"+"\n";// Opening the second tab
macro += "TAB T=1"+"\n";// Open the tab
macro += "TAG POS=12 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:close"+"\n"; // Close download menu
iimPlay(macro) // Run the variable
}
```

Hope this is what your looking for?

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what I need. I need not just skip this error and continue. I need to execute a certain code (enter other data into the form) if the item is not exists on the page. It should be more like if else.

Comment: guess you might need to record a video of your task and show us what you are doing during the "if-else" scenario, so we can understand your query better... :)